# Cloudbuild trigger that builds when tag is pushed is not invoked automatically

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I've created a cloudbuild trigger that should fire a when a tag matching the regex is pushed to the repository.

The regex is `^production/widget_(.+)$` and the UI is showing that multiple tags are matched. When pushing a new tag that matches the regex, I would expect it the cloudbuild trigger to start a new build.

The tags are formatted like this for instance: `production/widget_1.0_1745`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what exactly the problem was but after I changed the path structure to `production/widget/1.0.1` and adjusted the regex accordingly, cloudbuild is picking up newly pushed tags

### Update

After some time I figured out that the push tag invocation can get prevented by file filters if these don't allow a build to trigger.